# Can I filter out which pattern to match without having to copy out each case/condition?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, parsing, functional-programming, tokenize

I am trying to match statements based on a condition beforehand (I believe this is the closest thing Python has to switch statements). I am using Python 3.10

My code:

```
def _state(cur_codepoint:str, reconsume:bool):
    if reconsume == True:
        codepoint = cur_codepoint #consume current codepoint
    else:
        codepoint = consume_next_input_char() #consume new/next codepoint
    match codepoint:
        case '':
                switch_to_state() 
        case _:
                pass #Do something
```

How can I make this more efficient?

Comment: That's not the intended use case for Python's match statement. The match statement is not optimised for constant cases; it's effectively equivalent to a series of conditionals. If most actions are just a state transition, you could start with a lookup table which directly gives you the new state, and only execute the test if the lookup fails. (Of course, you have to manage to construct the lookup table only once; otherwise, you're not saving anything.)

Comment: @rici Could you explain further about your lookup table suggestion? How would this look in Python, considering there are almost 80 states and why exactly does it only have to be constructed once?

Comment: Either you define a dictionary keyed by state whose values are dictionaries keyed by input, or you define one dict whose keys are tuples of state and input. It doesn't make much difference. It needs to be constructed only once because construction is expensive. If you constructed one every time you enter a state, or worse every time you read a character, the dictionary construction time will overwhelm everything else. Probably the best architecture is to put the lexer in a class and make the lookup table(s) a class member.

Comment: @rici I will look into using a dictionary in the ways you have suggested and that explanation makes perfect sense. As for creating a lexer class, I am unfamiliar with using OOP, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Read a book about OOP :-)

Comment: @rici I posted a new question with my attempt at your dictionary suggestion, could you take a look?